# Use deferred statements with javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to understand jQuery deferred statements. In this case, I'd like to use a deferred statement when a javascript function finishes.

For example, when level objects have finished loading, do something...

But I can't attach `done()` to a javascript function:

```
    loadLevelObjects(game.data.levelObjects).done(function () {     
        //do something
    });
```

Or this method, perhaps using a `deferred()`:

```
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    loadLevelObjects(game.data.levelObjects).then do dfd.resolve();

    dfd.done(function () {
          //do something
    });
```

How can I mix jQuery with javascript functions? I guess one way to do it would be to rewrite `loadLevelObjects()` as a jQuery plugin... but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: If you have an async function, you should make it return a promise.  If you don't, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `.then()` or `.done()` methods of jQuery deferreds or promises, your function has to return a promise.  It's the promise that has those methods.

So, if `loadLevelObjects()` returns a promise, then you can do:

```
loadLevelObjects().done(function() {...})
```

---

If `loadLevelObjects()` is not asynchronous, then there's no need to use `.done()` as you can just write code sequentially:

```
loadLevelObjects();
// next line of code here
doSomethingElse();
```

---

Async functions (mostly ajax in client-side Javascript) already returns a promise in jQuery so you can directly use that promise without creating your own:

```
$.ajax(...).done(function() {...});
```

Or, if the ajax call is inside a function, you can return the promise from the function:

```
function loadLevelObjects(arg1, arg2) {
    // do some processing of arguments here
    return $.ajax(...)
}

loadLevelObjects(...).done(function(result) {
    // code here when loadLevelObjects async ajax call is done
});
```

---

The important thing to understand is that promises have no magic.  The `.then()` and `.done()` methods are methods on a promise object.  So, if you want to use them on a function call, then that function MUST return a promise object and that promise object must be resolved or rejected when the underlying function is done.  For most cases in client-side jQuery, you don't have to create your own promise or manually resolve or reject it as you can just use the promises that jQuery already creates whenever it does an async operation.